# How to use rayTestSingle having absolut coordinates of mesh triangles and ray start/end?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, bullet, raycasting

I have created a simple `btCollisionShape` (from a triMesh made from one triangle):

```
btTriangleMesh *mTriMesh = new btTriangleMesh();

btVector3 v0(1, 1,0);
btVector3 v1(-1,-1,0);
btVector3 v2(1,-1,0);

mTriMesh->addTriangle(v0,v1,v2);

btCollisionShape *mTriMeshShape = new btBvhTriangleMeshShape(mTriMesh,true);
```

I have created `ClosestRayResultCallback`

```
btVector3 Start(-1, -1,-1);
btVector3 End(1,1,1);

btCollisionWorld::ClosestRayResultCallback RayCallback(Start, End);
```

How can I perform a [`btCollisionWorld::rayTestSingle`](http://bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtCollisionWorld.html#aca2a9413508b4a2449fe83ff93ea564e) on my `btCollisionShape` having my ray Start and End and no Transformations applired?

Meanwhile I tried rayccast on whole world (that I actually do not need) but it seems I do it wrong =( as I see no [`hasHit`](http://bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/structbtCollisionWorld_1_1RayResultCallback.html#aae67fea02049a28c09ed6c3807611b57):

```
int i;

btDefaultCollisionConfiguration* collisionConfiguration = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();

btCollisionDispatcher* dispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration);

btBroadphaseInterface* overlappingPairCache = new btDbvtBroadphase();

btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver* solver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver;

btDiscreteDynamicsWorld* World = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher,overlappingPairCache,solver,collisionConfiguration);

btTriangleMesh *mTriMesh = new btTriangleMesh();

btVector3 v0(1, 1,0);
btVector3 v1(-1,-1,0);
btVector3 v2(1,-1,0);

mTriMesh->addTriangle(v0,v1,v2);

btCollisionShape *mTriMeshShape = new btBvhTriangleMeshShape(mTriMesh,true);
btCollisionObject *mTriMeshCO = new btCollisionObject ();

mTriMeshCO->setCollisionShape(mTriMeshShape);
World->addCollisionObject(mTriMeshCO);
btVector3 End(-1, -1,-1);
btVector3 Start(1,1,1);

btCollisionWorld::ClosestRayResultCallback RayCallback(Start, End);

World->rayTest(Start, End, RayCallback);

if(RayCallback.hasHit()) {
    btVector3 End = RayCallback.m_hitPointWorld;
    btVector3 Normal = RayCallback.m_hitNormalWorld;

    // Do some clever stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Please see the above image. I tried to draw your triangle and the ray-cast vector. The ray-cast vector intersects with the XY plane at (0,0,0). Now, the point (0,0,0) is actually lying on the edge of the triangle. It is implementation dependent that the ray-cast algorithm returns a hit-test true if the hit is lying on the edge. If you are testing this, why don't you try with a modified ray-cast vector which you know for sure is hitting the triangle inside it?

Comment: well I also get none results with btVector3 v0(0, 1,0); - be free to use it or one you like - edge cases was not the point of my question - basic use of Bullet was...(

Comment: OK, you managed to get me hooked me on to this. I was also searching for one of this kind. I downloaded the SDK and played around with it a while. With Microsoft Visual Studio 9, I managed to compile this code and for me the hitTest() is succeeding. To recheck, I even tried with a faraway ray and it was not giving any hit as expected. Which platform do you use?

Comment: Windows 7, x64, VS 2010 Ultimate, no extension used (CUDA\Intell compiler etc).. May be my includes are some kind wrong? How did your end code looked like?

Comment: Anyway my main intrest is in rayTestSingle... So if youll get anywhere in it I'll be super glad!=)

Comment: I created a basic windows application with the wizard, copied your function and code. Called this as the first function in the beginning of main(). See it here(http://codepad.org/6fLV2A8D). I just tried with Windows 7, x64, VS 2010 Premium combination and it works well there as well. Please note that I had compiled the the static libraries from Bullet all myself in the same configuration.